# PHP string syntax error in data attribute

Tags: php, json, string

This is the correct syntax `<div class="d" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4}'>`

And my php code `$output .= '<div class="fashmag-gallery-half" data-slick="">';`

I have tried but no luck, what's wrong here?

`$output .= '<div class="fashmag-gallery-half" data-slick="{"slidesToShow": 4}">';`

Comment: Do you get an actual error? What is your expected vs actual output? We can't help you if we don't actually know what's going wrong. If I were to guess, it's because of the doublequotes inside doublequotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put single quotes around the data attribute, since it uses double quotes inside. Since you're also using single quotes around the PHP string, you'll need to escape those quotes.

```
$output .= '<div class="fashmag-gallery-half" data-slick=\'{"slidesToShow": 4}\'>';
```

You could also use here-doc syntax:

```
$output .= <<<EOS
<div class="fashmag-gallery-half" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4}'>
EOS ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't write double quotes like that

it should be something like

```
$output .= "<div class=\"fashmag-gallery-half\" data-slick=\"{\"slidesToShow\": 4}\">";
```

Comment: You can't use single quotes in JSON syntax.

Comment: almost forgot that :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the generated HTML would not have properly escaped quotes so `data-slick="{"slidesToShow": 4}"` would cause a syntax error. Try escaping them with `data-slick="{\"slidesToShow\": 4}"` or better yet remove the quotes from the object inside like this: `data-slick="{ slidesToShow: 4}"`